# How to drag&drop elements onto a calendar with angular directives only

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, calendar, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement a drag&drop calendar with angular directives. The calendar uses the ui-calendar (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar), a complete AngularJS directive for the Arshaw FullCalendar.

The drag&drop of the element onto the calendar is powered by angular-dragdrop (https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).

Here is [my try](https://c9.io/milounas/demo) in the folder demo/ui-calendar/demo , but no event is ever fired when i drop an element onto the calendar...

The html is as simple as following:

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="calendarDemoApp" id="top" class="ng-scope">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-block-transitions{transition:0s all!important;-webkit-transition:0s all!important;}</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendarDemo.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="calendar.js"></script>

    <script>
      $.fn.ngattr = function(name, value) {
        var element = angular.element(this).get(0);
        return element.getAttribute(name) || element.getAttribute('data-' + name);
      };
    </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="dragdropController">

            <ul>
                <li class="btn btn-primary" 
                    ng-repeat='item in list1' 
                    ng-show="item.title" 
                    data-drag="true" 
                    data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}" 
                    ng-model="list1" 
                    jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, animate: true, placeholder: 'keep'}">{{item.title}}</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="alert-success calAlert" ng-show="alertMessage != undefined && alertMessage != ''">
            <h4>{{alertMessage}}</h4>
            </div>

            <div ng-controller="CalendarCtrl" select="renderCalender(myCalendar1);">
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addEvent()">Add Event</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-drop="true"
                     jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}" 
                     id="calendar" 
                     class="calendar" 
                     ng-model="eventSources" 
                     calendar="myCalendar1" 
                     config="uiConfig.calendar"
                     ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I merged all the directives, controlers and service in the following js file for the sake of simplicity:

```
function CalendarCtrl($scope) {
    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.events = [
      {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date()}
    ];

    /* add custom event*/
    $scope.addEvent = function() {
      $scope.events.push({
        title: 'Open Sesame',
        start: new Date(),
        className: ['openSesame']
      });
    };

   $scope.drop = function(date, allDay){
        $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Droped on ' + date);
    };

    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        drop: $scope.drop
      }
    };
    /* event sources array*/
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

}

angular.module('calendarDemoApp', [])

.constant('uiCalendarConfig', {})

.controller('dragdropController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var addEvent = function (title, length) {
        length = length.length == 0 ? "0" : length;
        title = title.length == 0 ? "Untitled Event (" + length + " min)" : title + " (" + length + " min)";
        $scope.list1.push({'title': title, 'length': length});

    }

    $('#event_add').unbind('click').click(function () {
        var title = $('#event_title').val();
        var length = $('#event_length').val();
        addEvent(title, length);
    });

    $scope.list1 = [
        {title: 'Full check up', length: '25'},
        {title: 'Whitening', length: '90'},
        {title: 'Filling', length: '30'}];
}])

.controller('uiCalendarCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

      var sourceSerialId = 1,
          eventSerialId = 1,
          sources = $scope.eventSources,
          extraEventSignature = $scope.calendarWatchEvent ? $scope.calendarWatchEvent : angular.noop,

          wrapFunctionWithScopeApply = function(functionToWrap){
              var wrapper;

              if (functionToWrap){
                  wrapper = function(){
                      // This happens outside of angular context so we need to wrap it in a timeout which has an implied apply.
                      // In this way the function will be safely executed on the next digest.

                      var args = arguments;
                      $timeout(function(){
                          functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
                      });
                  };
              }

              return wrapper;
          };

      this.eventsFingerprint = function(e) {
        if (!e.__uiCalId) {
          e.__uiCalId = eventSerialId++;
        }
        // This extracts all the information we need from the event. http://jsperf.com/angular-calendar-events-fingerprint/3
        return "" + e.__uiCalId + (e.id || '') + (e.title || '') + (e.url || '') + (+e.start || '') + (+e.end || '') +
          (e.allDay || '') + (e.className || '') + extraEventSignature(e) || '';
      };

      this.sourcesFingerprint = function(source) {
          return source.__id || (source.__id = sourceSerialId++);
      };

      this.allEvents = function() {
        // return sources.flatten(); but we don't have flatten
        var arraySources = [];
        for (var i = 0, srcLen = sources.length; i < srcLen; i++) {
          var source = sources[i];
          if (angular.isArray(source)) {
            // event source as array
            arraySources.push(source);
          } else if(angular.isObject(source) && angular.isArray(source.events)){
            // event source as object, ie extended form
            var extEvent = {};
            for(var key in source){
              if(key !== '_uiCalId' && key !== 'events'){
                 extEvent[key] = source[key];
              }
            }
            for(var eI = 0;eI < source.events.length;eI++){
              angular.extend(source.events[eI],extEvent);
            }
            arraySources.push(source.events);
          }
        }

        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arraySources);
      };

      // Track changes in array by assigning id tokens to each element and watching the scope for changes in those tokens
      // arguments:
      //  arraySource array of function that returns array of objects to watch
      //  tokenFn function(object) that returns the token for a given object
      this.changeWatcher = function(arraySource, tokenFn) {
        var self;
        var getTokens = function() {
          var array = angular.isFunction(arraySource) ? arraySource() : arraySource;
          var result = [], token, el;
          for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
            el = array[i];
            token = tokenFn(el);
            map[token] = el;
            result.push(token);
          }
          return result;
        };
        // returns elements in that are in a but not in b
        // subtractAsSets([4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 7]) => [6]
        var subtractAsSets = function(a, b) {
          var result = [], inB = {}, i, n;
          for (i = 0, n = b.length; i < n; i++) {
            inB[b[i]] = true;
          }
          for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (!inB[a[i]]) {
              result.push(a[i]);
            }
          }
          return result;
        };

        // Map objects to tokens and vice-versa
        var map = {};

        var applyChanges = function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
          var i, n, el, token;
          var replacedTokens = {};
          var removedTokens = subtractAsSets(oldTokens, newTokens);
          for (i = 0, n = removedTokens.length; i < n; i++) {
            var removedToken = removedTokens[i];
            el = map[removedToken];
            delete map[removedToken];
            var newToken = tokenFn(el);
            // if the element wasn't removed but simply got a new token, its old token will be different from the current one
            if (newToken === removedToken) {
              self.onRemoved(el);
            } else {
              replacedTokens[newToken] = removedToken;
              self.onChanged(el);
            }
          }

          var addedTokens = subtractAsSets(newTokens, oldTokens);
          for (i = 0, n = addedTokens.length; i < n; i++) {
            token = addedTokens[i];
            el = map[token];
            if (!replacedTokens[token]) {
              self.onAdded(el);
            }
          }
        };
        return self = {
          subscribe: function(scope, onChanged) {
            scope.$watch(getTokens, function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
              if (!onChanged || onChanged(newTokens, oldTokens) !== false) {
                applyChanges(newTokens, oldTokens);
              }
            }, true);
          },
          onAdded: angular.noop,
          onChanged: angular.noop,
          onRemoved: angular.noop
        };
      };

      this.getFullCalendarConfig = function(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig){
          var config = {};

          angular.extend(config, uiCalendarConfig);
          angular.extend(config, calendarSettings);

          angular.forEach(config, function(value,key){
            if (typeof value === 'function'){
              config[key] = wrapFunctionWithScopeApply(config[key]);
            }
          });

          return config;
      };
  }])

.directive('jqyouiDraggable', ['ngDragDropService', function(ngDragDropService) {
    return {
      require: '?jqyouiDroppable',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var dragSettings, jqyouiOptions, zIndex;
        var updateDraggable = function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            dragSettings = scope.$eval(element.attr('jqyoui-draggable') || element.attr('data-jqyoui-draggable')) || {};
            jqyouiOptions = scope.$eval(attrs.jqyouiOptions) || {};
            element
              .draggable({disabled: false})
              .draggable(jqyouiOptions)
              .draggable({
                start: function(event, ui) {
                  zIndex = angular.element(jqyouiOptions.helper ? ui.helper : this).css('z-index');
                  angular.element(jqyouiOptions.helper ? ui.helper : this).css('z-index', 9999);
                  angular.startXY = angular.element(this).offset();
                  ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dragSettings.onStart, event, ui);
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                  angular.element(jqyouiOptions.helper ? ui.helper : this).css('z-index', zIndex);
                  ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dragSettings.onStop, event, ui);
                },
                drag: function(event, ui) {
                  ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dragSettings.onDrag, event, ui);
                }
              });
          } else {
            element.draggable({disabled: true});
          }
        };
        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.$eval(attrs.drag); }, updateDraggable);
        updateDraggable();

        element.on('$destroy', function() {
          element.draggable('destroy');
        });
      }
    };
  }])

.directive('jqyouiDroppable', ['ngDragDropService', function(ngDragDropService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 1,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var dropSettings;
        var updateDroppable = function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            dropSettings = scope.$eval(angular.element(element).attr('jqyoui-droppable') || angular.element(element).attr('data-jqyoui-droppable')) || {};
            element
              .droppable({disabled: false})
              .droppable(scope.$eval(attrs.jqyouiOptions) || {})
              .droppable({
                over: function(event, ui) {
                  ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dropSettings.onOver, event, ui);
                },
                out: function(event, ui) {
                  ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dropSettings.onOut, event, ui);
                },
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                  if (angular.element(ui.draggable).ngattr('ng-model') && attrs.ngModel) {
                    ngDragDropService.invokeDrop(scope, angular.element(ui.draggable), angular.element(this), event, ui);
                  } else {
                    ngDragDropService.callEventCallback(scope, dropSettings.onDrop, event, ui);
                  }
                }
              });
          } else {
            element.droppable({disabled: true});
          }
        };

        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.$eval(attrs.drop); }, updateDroppable);
        updateDroppable();

        element.on('$destroy', function() {
          element.droppable('destroy');
        });
      }
    };
  }])

.directive('uiCalendar', ['uiCalendarConfig', '$locale', function(uiCalendarConfig, $locale) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {eventSources:'=ngModel',calendarWatchEvent: '&'},
        controller: 'uiCalendarCtrl',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

            var sources = scope.eventSources,
                sourcesChanged = false,
                eventSourcesWatcher = controller.changeWatcher(sources, controller.sourcesFingerprint),
                eventsWatcher = controller.changeWatcher(controller.allEvents, controller.eventsFingerprint),
                options = null;

            function getOptions(){
                var calendarSettings = attrs.uiCalendar ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.uiCalendar) : {},
                fullCalendarConfig;
                fullCalendarConfig = controller.getFullCalendarConfig(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig);

                options = { eventSources: sources };
                angular.extend(options, fullCalendarConfig);

                var options2 = {};
                for(var o in options){
                    if(o !== 'eventSources'){
                      options2[o] = options[o];
                    }
                }
                return JSON.stringify(options2);
            }

            scope.destroy = function(){
              if(attrs.calendar) {
                scope.calendar = scope.$parent[attrs.calendar] =  elm.html('');
              } else {
                scope.calendar = elm.html('');
              }
            };

            scope.init = function(){
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar(options);
            };

            eventSourcesWatcher.onAdded = function(source) {
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
              sourcesChanged = true;
            };

            eventSourcesWatcher.onRemoved = function(source) {
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source);
              sourcesChanged = true;
            };

            eventsWatcher.onAdded = function(event) {
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
            };

            eventsWatcher.onRemoved = function(event) {
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(e) { return e === event; });
            };

            eventsWatcher.onChanged = function(event) {
              scope.calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
            };

            eventSourcesWatcher.subscribe(scope);
            eventsWatcher.subscribe(scope, function(newTokens, oldTokens) {
              if (sourcesChanged === true) {
                sourcesChanged = false;
                // prevent incremental updates in this case
                return false;
              }
            });

            scope.$watch(getOptions, function(newO,oldO){
                scope.destroy();
                scope.init();
            });
      }
    };
}])

.service('ngDragDropService', ['$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse) {
    this.callEventCallback = function (scope, callbackName, event, ui) {
      if (!callbackName) return;

      var objExtract = extract(callbackName),
          callback = objExtract.callback,
          constructor = objExtract.constructor,
          args = [event, ui].concat(objExtract.args);

      // call either $scoped method i.e. $scope.dropCallback or constructor's method i.e. this.dropCallback
      scope.$apply((scope[callback] || scope[constructor][callback]).apply(scope, args));

      function extract(callbackName) {
        var atStartBracket = callbackName.indexOf('(') !== -1 ? callbackName.indexOf('(') : callbackName.length,
            atEndBracket = callbackName.lastIndexOf(')') !== -1 ? callbackName.lastIndexOf(')') : callbackName.length,
            args = callbackName.substring(atStartBracket + 1, atEndBracket), // matching function arguments inside brackets
            constructor = callbackName.match(/^[^.]+.\s*/)[0].slice(0, -1); // matching a string upto a dot to check ctrl as syntax
            constructor = scope[constructor] && typeof scope[constructor].constructor === 'function' ? constructor : null;

        return {
          callback: callbackName.substring(constructor && constructor.length + 1 || 0, atStartBracket),
          args: (args && args.split(',') || []).map(function(item) { return $parse(item)(scope); }),
          constructor: constructor
        }
      }
    };

    this.invokeDrop = function (scope, $draggable, $droppable, event, ui) {
      var dragModel = '',
        dropModel = '',
        dragSettings = {},
        dropSettings = {},
        jqyoui_pos = null,
        dragItem = {},
        dropItem = {},
        dragModelValue,
        dropModelValue,
        $droppableDraggable = null,
        droppableScope = $droppable.scope(),
        draggableScope = $draggable.scope();

      dragModel = $draggable.ngattr('ng-model');
      dropModel = $droppable.ngattr('ng-model');
      dragModelValue = draggableScope.$eval(dragModel);
      dropModelValue = droppableScope.$eval(dropModel);

      $droppableDraggable = $droppable.find('[jqyoui-draggable]:last,[data-jqyoui-draggable]:last');
      dropSettings = droppableScope.$eval($droppable.attr('jqyoui-droppable') || $droppable.attr('data-jqyoui-droppable')) || [];
      dragSettings = draggableScope.$eval($draggable.attr('jqyoui-draggable') || $draggable.attr('data-jqyoui-draggable')) || [];

      // Helps pick up the right item
      dragSettings.index = this.fixIndex(draggableScope, dragSettings, dragModelValue);
      dropSettings.index = this.fixIndex(droppableScope, dropSettings, dropModelValue);

      jqyoui_pos = angular.isArray(dragModelValue) ? dragSettings.index : null;
      dragItem = angular.isArray(dragModelValue) ? dragModelValue[jqyoui_pos] : dragModelValue;


      if (angular.isArray(dropModelValue) && dropSettings && dropSettings.index !== undefined) {
        dropItem = dropModelValue[dropSettings.index];
      } else if (!angular.isArray(dropModelValue)) {
        dropItem = dropModelValue;
      } else {
        dropItem = {};
      }

      if (dragSettings.animate === true) {
        this.move($draggable, $droppableDraggable.length > 0 ? $droppableDraggable : $droppable, null, 'fast', dropSettings, null);
        this.move($droppableDraggable.length > 0 && !dropSettings.multiple ? $droppableDraggable : [], $draggable.parent('[jqyoui-droppable],[data-jqyoui-droppable]'), angular.startXY, 'fast', dropSettings, angular.bind(this, function() {
          $timeout(angular.bind(this, function() {
            // Do not move this into move() to avoid flickering issue
            $draggable.css({'position': 'relative', 'left': '', 'top': ''});
            // Angular v1.2 uses ng-hide to hide an element not display property
            // so we've to manually remove display:none set in this.move()
            $droppableDraggable.css({'position': 'relative', 'left': '', 'top': '', 'display': ''});

            this.mutateDraggable(draggableScope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dragModel, dropModel, dropItem, $draggable);
            this.mutateDroppable(droppableScope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dropModel, dragItem, jqyoui_pos);
            this.callEventCallback(droppableScope, dropSettings.onDrop, event, ui);
          }));
        }));
      } else {
        $timeout(angular.bind(this, function() {
          this.mutateDraggable(draggableScope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dragModel, dropModel, dropItem, $draggable);
          this.mutateDroppable(droppableScope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dropModel, dragItem, jqyoui_pos);
          this.callEventCallback(droppableScope, dropSettings.onDrop, event, ui);
        }));
      }
    };

    this.move = function($fromEl, $toEl, toPos, duration, dropSettings, callback) {
      if ($fromEl.length === 0) {
        if (callback) {
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            callback();
          }, 300);
        }
        return false;
      }

      var zIndex = 9999,
        fromPos = $fromEl.offset(),
        wasVisible = $toEl && $toEl.is(':visible'),
        hadNgHideCls = $toEl.hasClass('ng-hide');

      if (toPos === null && $toEl.length > 0) {
        if (($toEl.attr('jqyoui-draggable') || $toEl.attr('data-jqyoui-draggable')) !== undefined && $toEl.ngattr('ng-model') !== undefined && $toEl.is(':visible') && dropSettings && dropSettings.multiple) {
          toPos = $toEl.offset();
          if (dropSettings.stack === false) {
            toPos.left+= $toEl.outerWidth(true);
          } else {
            toPos.top+= $toEl.outerHeight(true);
          }
        } else {
          // Angular v1.2 uses ng-hide to hide an element 
          // so we've to remove it in order to grab its position
          if (hadNgHideCls) $toEl.removeClass('ng-hide');
          toPos = $toEl.css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'block'}).offset();
          $toEl.css({'visibility': '','display': wasVisible ? 'block' : 'none'});
        }
      }

      $fromEl.css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': zIndex})
        .css(fromPos)
        .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
          // Angular v1.2 uses ng-hide to hide an element
          // and as we remove it above, we've to put it back to
          // hide the element (while swapping) if it was hidden already
          // because we remove the display:none in this.invokeDrop()
          if (hadNgHideCls) $toEl.addClass('ng-hide');
          if (callback) callback();
        });
    };

    this.mutateDroppable = function(scope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dropModel, dragItem, jqyoui_pos) {
      var dropModelValue = scope.$eval(dropModel);

      scope.dndDragItem = dragItem;

      if (angular.isArray(dropModelValue)) {
        if (dropSettings && dropSettings.index >= 0) {
          dropModelValue[dropSettings.index] = dragItem;
        } else {
          dropModelValue.push(dragItem);
        }
        if (dragSettings && dragSettings.placeholder === true) {
          dropModelValue[dropModelValue.length - 1]['jqyoui_pos'] = jqyoui_pos;
        }
      } else {
        $parse(dropModel + ' = dndDragItem')(scope);
        if (dragSettings && dragSettings.placeholder === true) {
          dropModelValue['jqyoui_pos'] = jqyoui_pos;
        }
      }
    };

    this.mutateDraggable = function(scope, dropSettings, dragSettings, dragModel, dropModel, dropItem, $draggable) {
      var isEmpty = angular.equals(angular.copy(dropItem), {}),
        dragModelValue = scope.$eval(dragModel);

      scope.dndDropItem = dropItem;

      if (dragSettings && dragSettings.placeholder) {
        if (dragSettings.placeholder != 'keep'){
          if (angular.isArray(dragModelValue) && dragSettings.index !== undefined) {
            dragModelValue[dragSettings.index] = dropItem;
          } else {
            $parse(dragModel + ' = dndDropItem')(scope);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (angular.isArray(dragModelValue)) {
          if (isEmpty) {
            if (dragSettings && ( dragSettings.placeholder !== true && dragSettings.placeholder !== 'keep' )) {
              dragModelValue.splice(dragSettings.index, 1);
            }
          } else {
            dragModelValue[dragSettings.index] = dropItem;
          }
        } else {
          // Fix: LIST(object) to LIST(array) - model does not get updated using just scope[dragModel] = {...}
          // P.S.: Could not figure out why it happened
          $parse(dragModel + ' = dndDropItem')(scope);
          if (scope.$parent) {
            $parse(dragModel + ' = dndDropItem')(scope.$parent);
          }
        }
      }

      $draggable.css({'z-index': '', 'left': '', 'top': ''});
    };

    this.fixIndex = function(scope, settings, modelValue) {
      if (settings.applyFilter && angular.isArray(modelValue) && modelValue.length > 0) {
        var dragModelValueFiltered = scope[settings.applyFilter](),
            lookup = dragModelValueFiltered[settings.index],
            actualIndex = undefined;

        modelValue.forEach(function(item, i) {
           if (angular.equals(item, lookup)) {
             actualIndex = i;
           }
        });

        return actualIndex;
      }

      return settings.index;
    };
  }])
;
```

Comment: Did you get this to work ever?

Comment: Yes Anders answer was correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't used angular-dragdrop, but the documentation says that the config object should contain a onDrop property. Try replacing `jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}"` with `jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'drop'}"`. angular-dragdrop seem to expect `onDrop` to be a string with the name of a function on the scope.

Comment: Thank Anders! I am trying to fire the drop event of the calendar though, and it is still dead quiet :(

Comment: So you mean that your $scope.drop() method isn't called at all, even with the change I mentioned?

Comment: Yes $scope.drop was call thanks to the callback but it was supposed to be called from the drop function in the $scope.uiConfig so I can get the calendar date where the element was drop onto.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is use JqueryUI draggable. Create directive and pass the attributes via "elem".  You can include title as an attribute as well.

```html
.directive('dragMe', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.data('event', {
          title: $.trim($(elem).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
          stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });
      elem.draggable({
          zIndex: 999,
          revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
          revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    }
  };
})
```