# What options I have to implement drag&drop of elements onto ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs

I want to achieve a drag&drop of elements in the page onto ui-calendar.

Same question has been asked but using angular-dragdrop directive.
[How to drag&drop elements onto a calendar with angular directives only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368621/how-to-dragdrop-elements-onto-a-calendar-with-angular-directives-only)

What are my options to implement this drag&drop ?

An other resource found on the github issue tracker of ui-calendar: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/43

I have try by using ngDraggable but without success, the onDrop of the calendar is not called.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read follow this [Article's](http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html) steps . It's native angularjs directives. It helps me a lot.